# Can you use DragDetect in a subclassed window?

Tags: c++, winapi, drag, subclassing

Let's say you're subclassing Explorer's items view, and you'd like to detect drag events using `DragDetect`. Is that possible?

I tried doing it, basically doing the following in `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`:

```
CPoint pt(lParam);
::ClientToScreen(m_wndItemsView, &pt);

if (DragDetect(m_wndItemsView, pt))
{
    ATLTRACE(L"\ndrag\n");
}
```

This seems to work and detect dragging, but it also screws up mouse clicks in Explorer. They get delayed or suppressed or something.  Is that expected?  I also tried calling the `DefWindowProc` before my own subclass processing, but that didn't fix the problem.  Any input is appreciated.

Comment: DragDetect works by running a message loop and swallowing messages until either the button is released or the mouse moves far enough. Messages it swallows don't get seen by Explorer. You may have more luck by subclassing the parent window and seeing if it gets a notification message to indicate d&d has started. In the old days when Explorer used a standard listview this would have been a `LVN_BEGINDRAG` notification; these days, who knows.

Comment: Thanks.  I think I'm just going to stick with manual drag detection using flags, system metrics, etc.

Comment: @loop123123 perhaps [`SetWinEventHook()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwineventhook) with `EVENT_SYSTEM_DRAGDROP(START|END)` events may suit your needs better?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Well I'd like to detect a drag in the background of the directory too--not just a file drag-drop operation.

Comment: @loop123123 What is your actual goal here? Why are you trying to detect drags at all? This is starting to feel like a possible [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/) to me.

Comment: @loop123123 Can you reproduce this issue on a simple application window (e.g. [Simple Drawing sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/18cbd05ee44455cd7552804dcf2c9d6db619b412/Samples/Win7Samples/begin/LearnWin32/SimpleDrawing))? Or could you show a mini, complete and reproducible sample?